# Using local datasource for the Tab control

Tags: sxa

I'm using the built in SXA Tabs control but I wanted to use it with a local data source i.e. a datasource beneath the Data folder of the page containing the Tab control.

Additionally, I'd like to be able to auto-create that datasource when the Tabs control is dropped on a page.

Is this possible with the built in control?

Comment: I am sure this feature would be available in SXA 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but you can already create a local data source for Tabs. Just drop Tabs on the page and it will ask you were to create its data source:

[image]

And it will create data source item here:

[image]

If you would like to have local data source created automatically for your Tabs rendering you can also do it. Find the rendering item and add this setting in the `Other properties` field:

[image]

Once it is done, you won't see the "Select the Associated Content" dialog for Tabs, it will always create a local data source for it.

**Important!** Keep in mind that all changes to the SXA items will get overridden with SXA update.